# Is anyone aware of any .NET OpenID Provider sample code that might exist?

Tags: .net, openid

I need to implement an OpenID Provider in .Net and wondered....Is there's any OpenSource code already written and available?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just found http://code.google.com/p/dotnetopenid/

Apologies for not search properly first.....

I don't seem to be able to delete this question (strange)

Instead, as penance, this question and answer will be marked community property so I don't benefit in any way from my stupidity..

Answer (score 2):

Also see [Hanselman's post](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/TheWeeklySourceCode25OpenIDEdition.aspx) about some of the details of using DotNetOpenID on your website. That one's been sitting around in my Bookmarks folders for a while now... :)

Comment: That blog post covers openId Consumer "Relying Party"" but not Provider.

Answer (score 0):

BTW - There is ExtremeSwank which is on Google Code too.  I'd check it out also, looks like it is further along at this time.

I have a blog entry I'm working up that should be published, at least starting on, tomorrow.  Working up a WCF OpenID Provider Implementation.  http://www.adronbhall.name.